# Usage of instaceof when polymorphism is not possible

Tags: java, instanceof

### **EDIT: This is not a duplicate because I am addressing on issue where the classes cannot be overloaded to achieve polymorphism. I am not asking for comparison between polymorphism vs instanceof. I am asking a very specific scenario-based question.**

I have read it `n` times online that one should always try to avoid the usage of `instanceof` operator, unless we are using it to implement the `.equals()` method of a class.

It was said that, whenever possible, we should try to achieve polymorphism rather than using `instanceof` to determine the type of the objects to decide the following actions.

**For example**: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

However, in this specific scenario where I do not have any available methods in the super & sub classes (other than the toString, equals, accessor & mutator methods). Is it a valid scenario to use `instanceof` ?

```
class Warrior
{

    int damage;
    int defense;
    Item handSlot;

    public Warrior(){
        damage = 0;
        defense = 0;
        handSlot = null;
    }

    private void equipHand(Item item)
    {
        //Determine class of object to decide further actions
        if (item instanceof Weapon){
            this.handSlot= item;
            this.damage += ((Weapon)item).getDamage();  
        }
        else if (item instanceof Shield){
            this.handSlot = item;
            this.defense += ((Shield)item).getProtection();
        }
    }
}


class Item
{
    private String name;
    public Item(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }       
}

class Shield extends Item
{
    private int protection;

    public Shield(String name, int protection){
        super(name);
        this.protection = protection;
    }

    public int getProtection(){
        return protection;
    }
}

class Weapon extends Item
{
    private int damage;

    public Weapon(String name, int damage){
        super(name);
        this.damage = damage;   
    }

    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }   
}
```

**Note that**, if `Weapon, Item & Shield class` have a overloaded method (for example: `equip()`), I can simply use polymorphism. But in this case, the equip method is in another class. **In this specific scenario**, **is it okay to use** `instanceof` **operator**? Or is it still a bad design?

Comment: Why not overload `equipHand(Item item)` with `equipHand(Weapon weapon)` and `equipHand(Shield shield)` as they look like they should both be handled in a different way.

Comment: Your question itself has answer "avoid whenever possible", if avoid not possible there is nothing wrong in using "instanceof"

Comment: @Oil that can be done, however the codes I shown above has been heavily cut down by me before posting here. Imagine if there are 100 possible items, I may have to write 100 overloaded methods that way. I am looking for a more universal approach.

Comment: As you know `Shield` and  `Weapon` both are extend `Item`. So better to override  `equipHand` method in each classes with their function. Direct access method with item instance instead of checking with `instance of`

Comment: @bmthaker So in short, you agree with what Oil said ? But won't it be a bad design when I have to write so many additional overloaded methods for every additional item class I add in?

Comment: @user3437460 To avoid additional overloaded method, Create different interface as per requirement.i.e. IWeapon, iShield like wise.Define specific methods in mention interface. To more clear read first chapter of `Head First Design Pattern` book, this will help you a lot.

Comment: @bmthaker Thankyou for your reply, you may consider putting down your answer here? It would be helpful for future programmers who visit this page.

Comment: @user3437460 welcome. Noted!!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to your design would be to move the `equipHand` method from `Warrior` to `Item` (perhaps renaming it in light of this as well):

```
/* in Item */
public abstract void giveToWarrior(Warrior w);

/* in Weapon */
@Override
public void giveToWarrior(Warrior w) {
    w.setHandSlot(this);
    w.increaseDamageBy(getDamage());
}

/* in Shield */
@Override
public void giveToWarrior(Warrior w) {
    w.setHandSlot(this);
    w.increaseProtectionBy(getProtection());
}
```

(I've used some methods that do not exist in `Warrior`, but their functions should be self-explanatory. Making the indicated change would require implementing these methods.)

This design resolves the major issue with your current design, namely that it will become cumbersome to add new `Item` subclasses since doing so would require updating `equipHand` as well.

Comment: This is what I was trying to overcome, and you addressed directly to what I asked. Nice implementation. Already +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

As you know `Shield` and  `Weapon` both are extend `Item`. So better to override  `equipHand` method in each classes with their function. Direct access method with `item` instance instead of checking with `instance of`.

The issue with above implementation, it will overload additional method for each class.

To avoid additional overloaded method, Create different interface as per requirement.i.e. **IWeapon**, **iShield** like wise. Define specific methods in mention interface. To more clear read first chapter of `Head First Design Pattern` book, this will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and book recommendation. ;)